# How to POST data from a form to a different server

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, post

I wanted to make a dashboard for a node.js app I created. I wanted to have the user fill out a form on the dashboard and then for the dashboard to send some data to a JSON database on the node.js server. I am using express on the node.js server, and the dashboard is using EJS and express as well.

I've looked around and could not find a helpful guide on how to send data to a node.js application, but couldn't find anything.

The node.js server (with the database) is hosted on an OVH VPS with Ubuntu. Here is what I want to make:

`User fills out form -> POST data from the form to database`

I hope one of you out there knows how to do this and is willing to help me!

Thank You!!!

Codingpro

Comment: What have you tried so far? The basic concept is in the front end do an AJAX/axios/etc request `axios.post('/form',data)` and on the backend `app.post('/form',function(req, res) { // handle req here })`

Comment: @whodini9 so is the backend the node.js OVH server and is the front end the dashboard?

Comment: Yes the frontend would be the dashboard here